# Brainf*ck interpreter written in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, brainfuck

I have written a program in x86 assembly (Intel syntax/MASM) that interprets brainfuck code that is fed to it via an interactive console and prints the final stack to stdout. Note that it does not include an implementation for the `,` command, but everything else has been implemented. The idea is that it presents the user with a prompt where they can enter their code; when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it evaluates it and then dumps the resultant cell state to the console. While the cell state is maintained between prompt entries, the pointer position is not.

It looks like this:

```
$++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
Hello World!

0 0 72 100 87 33 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
--------------------------------------------------
$>>[.>]
HdW!

0 0 72 100 87 33 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
--------------------------------------------------
$++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.
A
0 65 72 100 87 33 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
--------------------------------------------------
```

This is my first major foray into assembly, so I'm mainly looking for general tips, such as:

- Which registers I should be using in particular cases
- When I should be using RAM and when I should be using registers
- Ways that the code could be simplified

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
bfsrc BYTE 200 dup(0) ; buffer to store source code
bfcells BYTE 100 dup(0) ; 100-byte data array size for now
loopStack DD 5 dup(0) ; stores the position of the first instruction in the current loop. Maximum of 5 nested loops.
charBuf BYTE 5 dup(0) ; buffer for when we are dumping numbers
newline BYTE 10,0 ; ASCII 10 is \n
prompt BYTE "$",0 ; input prompt string
hr BYTE 50 dup('-'),0 ; fake horizontal rule
space BYTE ' ',0

.code

EvalBf proc
    start:
    ; print the prompt and then read input into the source array
    invoke StdOut, addr prompt
    invoke StdIn, addr bfsrc,200

    ; exit if input is empty
    cmp bfsrc,0
    je exit

    mov eax,0 ; eax is BF data pointer
    mov ebx,0 ; ebx is BF source pointer
    mov ecx,0 ; ecx is loop depth

    processInstruction:

    ; jump according to current source char
    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '+'
    je plus

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '-'
    je minus

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '>'
    je fwd

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '<'
    je back

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '['
    je open

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], ']'
    je close

    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '.'
    je dot

    ; By default, skip instruction if we haven't caught it
    jmp processNextInstruction

    plus:
    inc BYTE PTR bfcells[eax]
    jmp processNextInstruction

    minus:
    dec BYTE PTR bfcells[eax]
    jmp processNextInstruction

    fwd:
    inc eax
    jmp processNextInstruction

    back:
    dec eax
    jmp processNextInstruction

    open:
    ; push the current source position
    ; onto the loop stack
    mov loopStack[ecx*4],ebx
    inc ecx
    jmp processNextInstruction

    close:
    dec ecx
    cmp BYTE PTR bfcells[eax], 0
    ; break out of loop if data cell is 0
    je processNextInstruction
    ; pop the innermost loop position and
    ; set it as the next instruction
    mov ebx,loopStack[ecx*4]
    inc ecx
    jmp processNextInstruction

    dot:
    ; transfer current cell value into char buffer through dl
    mov dl, BYTE PTR bfcells[eax]
    mov BYTE PTR charBuf[0], dl
    ; follow the character with null to terminate the string
    mov BYTE PTR charBuf[1],0
    ; save the registers we need to maintain so that stdout doesn't break anything
    push eax
    push ecx
    ; print generated string
    invoke StdOut, addr charBuf
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    jmp processNextInstruction

    processNextInstruction:
    inc ebx
    ; we're finished if we have hit the end of the input
    cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], 0
    je done
    jmp processInstruction

    done:
    ; loop through every value in the BF data array and print it
    invoke StdOut, addr newline
    mov eax, 0
    printNext:
    ; the data array is 100 cells long, so stop looping when we hit cell 100
    cmp eax, 100
    jge reset

    ; save value in eax onto the stack
    push eax

    ; convert cell value to string and store it in the character buffer
    invoke dwtoa, BYTE PTR bfcells[eax], addr charBuf

    ; print the buffer, followed by a space
    invoke StdOut, addr charBuf
    invoke StdOut, addr space

    ; restore and increment value of eax
    pop eax
    inc eax
    jmp printNext

    ; when processing is complete, go back to the beginning and take new input
    reset:
    invoke StdOut, addr newline
    invoke StdOut, addr hr
    invoke StdOut, addr newline
    jmp start

    exit:
    invoke ExitProcess,0
EvalBf endp
end EvalBf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov eax,0 ; eax is BF data pointer
> mov ebx,0 ; ebx is BF source pointer
> mov ecx,0 ; ecx is loop depth
> ```

If you used the `EDI` register for the *BF data pointer* and the `ESI` register for the *BF source pointer*, not only would this be a more natural choice, you could also dismiss the `push eax`and `pop eax` around `invoke StdOut, addr charBuf`.
By further using `EBX` for the *loop depth* you can also eliminate the need for `push ecx`and `pop ecx` around the same `invoke StdOut, addr charBuf`.
Do note that clearing a register is better done trough an `xor` instruction:

```
xor  edi, edi ; EDI is BF data pointer
xor  esi, esi ; ESI is BF source pointer
xor  ebx, ebx ; EBX is loop depth
```

---

> ```
>  cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], 0
>  je done
>  jmp processInstruction
> done:
> ```

Here's a clear opportunity to optimize the code. Instead of conditionally jumping to *done* you can use the opposite conditional jump and fall through. This saves an instruction:

```
cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], 0
jne processInstruction
done:
```

---

> ```
> mov  eax, 0
> printNext:
> cmp  eax, 100
> jge  reset
> push eax
> ...
> pop  eax
> inc  eax
> jmp  printNext
> ```

You've used a WHILE-loop here. A REPEAT-loop would have been more optimal. Also a better way to zero a register is by `xor`-ing it with itself. Furthermore by using the `EDI` register you eliminate the need for the `push eax` and `pop eax`:

```
 xor edi, edi
printNext:
 ...
 inc edi
 cmp edi, 100
 jl printNext
reset:
```

---

> ```
> mov dl, BYTE PTR bfcells[eax]
> mov BYTE PTR charBuf[0], dl
> ; follow the character with null to terminate the string
> mov BYTE PTR charBuf[1],0
> ```

Use the `movzx` here and shave off an instruction:

```
movzx edx, BYTE PTR bfcells[eax]
mov WORD PTR charBuf[0], dx ; follow the character with null to terminate the string
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the review! I've seen that "`xor` to clear" pattern used fairly widely; why is that preferred? Is it faster, or just clearer to those who are experienced in Assembly? Also, how do I choose between using the general-purpose registers and using `EDI` and `ESI` (how do you know that those ones are safe)? Finally, it looks like you indented the code in your revised snippets; is that a preferred practice in assembly, even if there isn't a inherent place to do it in the language (e.g. there are no braces)?

Comment: `xor reg,reg` is the preferred way to zero a register because it has a shorter encoding (2 bytes against 5 for the `mov reg,0`) and because the manufacturer (Intel) made it extra fast precisely for doing that.

Comment: Registers like `EDI`, `ESI` and `EBX` are non-volatile, meaning that the code that uses these must preserve them. This implies e.g. that the code that performs `StdOut` will not change these registers. This allows you to have certain values in them without having to `push`/`pop` them around an `invoke StdOut ...`.

Comment: Indenting the code is strongly adviced because it makes the code much more readable. How you indent is a matter of personal taste. At the very least I think the labels should stand out from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `200` and `100` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `PROGRAM_MAX_LEN` or `DATA_MAX_LEN`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.

### Avoid obsolete tools and habits

These days, it's unlikely your computer is actually running with a 80386 processor, so it probably doesn't make much sense to use the `.386` directive at the top of the program.  Similarly, it appears that you're using "masm32" which based around a 32-bit architecture.  It probably makes more sense to use more modern tools and techniques such as using Microsoft's `ml64` or the open source `NASM` rather than the rather archaic `masm32` with its late 1990s (and probably not licensed) version of Microsoft's MASM.  If you're going to take the time to learn assembly language, it makes sense not to start with something that's already obsolete.

### Examine the listing file

When you write assembly language code, it's often very useful to look at the resulting listing file which shows exactly how the assembler has encoded your instructions.  For example, the code includes the following lines:

```
mov eax,0 ; eax is BF data pointer
mov ebx,0 ; ebx is BF source pointer
mov ecx,0 ; ecx is loop depth
```

Here's how they are encoded:

```
0000002C  B8 00000000           mov eax,0 ; eax is BF data pointer
00000031  BB 00000000           mov ebx,0 ; ebx is BF source pointer
00000036  B9 00000000           mov ecx,0 ; ecx is loop depth
```

As you can see, each of those instructions is 5 bytes long for a total of 15 bytes for these three instructions.  This helps to understand why some things are done the way they are, as in the following suggestion:

### Prefer shorter instructions

The common idiom in x86 assembly language programming (and in some other assembly languages as well) is to use the `xor` instruction to clear a register.  So the three lines mentioned above could be written like this:

```
xor eax,eax ; eax is BF data pointer
xor ebx,ebx ; ebx is BF source pointer
xor ecx,ecx ; ecx is loop depth
```

The resulting listing looks like this:

```
0000002C  33 C0         xor eax,eax ; eax is BF data pointer
0000002E  33 DB         xor ebx,ebx ; ebx is BF source pointer
00000030  33 C9         xor ecx,ecx ; ecx is loop depth
```

These are encoded as 2 bytes each for a total of 6 bytes saving 3 bytes per instruction or 9 bytes total.  This should make it clear why `xor` is preferred and why looking at the listing files is useful.

### Avoid unecessary branching

At the bottom of the loop, we have this

```
jmp printNext

; when processing is complete, go back to the beginning and take new input
reset:
invoke printf, addr newline
invoke printf, addr hr
invoke printf, addr newline
jmp start

exit:
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Note that the `reset` code always jumps to `start` and that the only way to get to `reset` is via a branching instruction (because the unconditional `jmp` preceeding it means that the code will never "fall through" to `reset`).

We can rearrange this to eliminate the `jmp start` by putting this code just above the `start` label:

```
reset:
    invoke printf, addr newline
    invoke printf, addr hr
    invoke printf, addr newline
    ;jmp start          NO LONGER NEEDED 

start::
```

Now the `jmp` is eliminated since `start` is the next location anyway.  Note that `start` now has two colons after it, making it a public symbol.  This is necessary because the `END` instruction must now be adjusted to be `END start` (or alternatively, use the `/entry:start` command line option).  Also, I have used the external C function `printf` instead of the masm32 things and started the labels at the left margin which is the most common style to format assembly language code.

In a similar vein, instead of this:

```
je done
jmp processInstruction

done:
```

write this:

```
jne processInstruction

done:
```

### Think carefully about data ordering

In the lines quoted above, the `hr` data is printed, surrounded by `newline`.  Further, the **only** time `hr` is used, it's printed this way.  This suggests a small optimization:

```
hr BYTE 10, 50 dup('-')  ; fake horizontal rule (ends with newline below)
newline BYTE 10,0 ; ASCII 10 is \n

invoke printf, addr hr   ; print newline, hr, newline
```

Now the `hr` line contains the leading newline (which is only a single additional byte) but eliminates the need for a terminating `0` because it actually gets terminated with the `newline` immediately below it.  Thus the data portion of the code actually remains the same size but the code is reduced from three calls to one.  If we look at the listing, it's a non-trivial savings.  Here's how it was originally:

```
                                invoke printf, addr newline
00000117  68 0000014F R   *     push   OFFSET newline
0000011C  E8 00000000 E   *     call   printf
00000121  83 C4 04     *        add    esp, 000000004h
                                invoke printf, addr hr
00000124  68 00000153 R   *     push   OFFSET hr
00000129  E8 00000000 E   *     call   printf
0000012E  83 C4 04     *        add    esp, 000000004h
                                invoke printf, addr newline
00000131  68 0000014F R   *     push   OFFSET newline
00000136  E8 00000000 E   *     call   printf
0000013B  83 C4 04     *        add    esp, 000000004h
0000013E  E9 FFFFFEBD           jmp start
```

The revised version (including the suggestion above) now looks like this:

```
                                invoke printf, addr hr
00000000  68 00000151 R   *     push   OFFSET hr
00000005  E8 00000000 E   *     call   printf
0000000A  83 C4 04     *        add    esp, 000000004h
                                ;jmp start
```

It's important to realize that although the `INVOKE` makes thing look small, there are actuallly several generated lines that result.  The combination of these two suggestions saves 31 bytes plus the runtime overhead of two function calls.

### Prefer registers to memory access

Register access is generally faster than memory access.  For that reason, for fast, small and efficient assembly language code, we generally think very carefully about register use.  One easy and obvious savings suggests itself when we look at the listing for the various `cmp` instructions:

```
0000003B  80 BB 0000000A R      cmp BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx], '+'
       2B
00000042  74 38         je plus
```

As you can see, each of the `cmp` instructions both accesses memory and is 7 bytes long.  We can do better:

```
mov al, BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx]
cmp al, '+'
je plus
```

Here is what that looks like in the listing:

```
0000003F  8A 83 0000000A R      mov al, BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx]
00000045  3C 2B         cmp al, '+'
00000047  74 1A         je plus
```

Now we simply load the instruction into the `al` register once and then compare it with the potential match.  This saves 29 bytes of code.  Also, I changed the code to use the `edi` register rather than the `eax` register for the BF data pointer.

### Consider data-driven versus code-driven code

The essential job of the interpreter is to read an instruction and then execute the corresponding code for it.  This suggests a table structure:

```
inst STRUC 
    token BYTE ?
    codeptr DD ?
inst ENDS

bf  inst {'+', plus}
    inst {'-', minus}
    inst {'>', fwd}
    inst {'<', back}
    inst {'[', open}
    inst {']', close}
    inst {'.', dot}
    inst { 0, dump}
    inst { 0, 0 }      ; end of list
```

Here's the code to use that structure:

```
processInstruction:
    ; get next token
    mov al, BYTE PTR bfsrc[ebx]
    ; reset the table pointer
    lea esi, bf
    ; push return location
    push processNextInstruction

nextinst:
    cmp inst.token[esi], al
    jne advance
    jmp inst.codeptr[esi]
advance:
    add esi, SIZEOF inst
    cmp inst.codeptr[esi], 0
    jne nextinst
    pop esi     ; throw away return value

processNextInstruction:
    inc ebx
    jmp processInstruction
EvalBf endp
```

Now each of the routines is made into a subroutine along these lines:

```
fwd PROC 
    inc edi
    ret
fwd endp 

open PROC
    ; push the current source position
    ; onto the loop stack
    mov loopStack[ecx*4],ebx
    inc ecx
    ret
open ENDP
```

It works by first pushing the location of `processNextInstruction`, then stepping through the table until it finds a matching token.  When the matching token is found, such as `fwd` above, then the code performs a `jmp` to the subroutine and the `ret` at the end of the subroutine causes the code to end up at `processNextInstruction`.

### Putting it all together

With most of those changes made (and a few more optimizations), here is what I get as a result:

```
.686
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

includelib msvcrt

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:DWORD
printf proto C:VARARG
putchar proto C, char:DWORD
getchar proto C
scanf proto C:VARARG

PROGRAM_MAX_LEN equ 200
DATA_MAX_LEN equ 100
MAX_NESTED_LOOPS equ 5

.data
bfsrc BYTE PROGRAM_MAX_LEN dup(0) ; buffer to store source code
bfcells BYTE DATA_MAX_LEN dup(0) ; data array 
; stores the position of the first instruction in the current loop. 
loopStack DD MAX_NESTED_LOOPS dup(0) 

.const
decfmt BYTE "%d ",0
scanfmt BYTE "%200s",0
prompt BYTE "$",0 ; input prompt string
hr BYTE 10, 50 dup('-')  ; fake horizontal rule (ends with newline below)
newline BYTE 10,0 ; ASCII 10 is \n

inst STRUC 
    token BYTE ?
    codeptr DD ?
inst ENDS

bf  inst {'+', plus}
    inst {'-', minus}
    inst {'>', fwd}
    inst {'<', back}
    inst {'[', open}
    inst {']', close}
    inst {'.', dot}
    inst {',', comma}
    inst { 0, dump}
    inst { 0, 0 }      ; end of list

.code

EvalBf proc
    ; print the prompt and then read input into the source array
    invoke printf, addr prompt
    lea ebx,bfsrc   ; ebx is BF source pointer
    invoke scanf, addr scanfmt, ebx

    lea edi,bfcells ; edi is BF data pointer
    xor ecx,ecx ; ecx is loop depth
    dec ebx

processNextInstruction:
    inc ebx

processInstruction:
    ; jump according to current source char
    mov al, BYTE PTR [ebx]
    lea esi, bf
    ; push return location
    push processNextInstruction

nextinst:
    cmp inst.token[esi], al
    jne advance
    jmp inst.codeptr[esi]
advance:
    add esi, SIZEOF inst
    cmp inst.codeptr[esi], 0
    jne nextinst
    ret                 ; actually goes to `processNextInstruction`
EvalBf endp

dump PROC
    pop esi         ; throw away return value
    push EvalBf     ; redirect to reset
    ; loop through every value in the BF data array and print it
    invoke printf, addr newline
    lea edi, bfcells
printNext:
    ; print the buffer, followed by a space
    movzx edx, BYTE PTR [edi]
    invoke printf, addr decfmt, edx

    ; advance the cell pointer
    inc edi
    ; the data array is 100 cells long, so stop looping when we hit cell 100
    cmp edi, OFFSET bfcells + DATA_MAX_LEN
    jb printNext
    ; when processing is complete, go back to the beginning and take new input
    invoke printf, addr hr
    ret
dump ENDP

exit PROC
    invoke ExitProcess,0
exit ENDP

plus PROC
    inc BYTE PTR [edi]
    ret
plus ENDP

minus PROC 
    dec BYTE PTR [edi]
    ret
minus ENDP 

fwd PROC 
    inc edi
    ret
fwd endp 

back PROC
    dec edi
    ret
back ENDP

open PROC
    ; push the current source position
    ; onto the loop stack
    mov loopStack[ecx*4],ebx
    inc ecx
    ret
open ENDP

close PROC
    dec ecx
    cmp BYTE PTR [edi], 0
    ; break out of loop if data cell is 0
    je endloop
    ; pop the innermost loop position and
    ; set it as the next instruction
    mov ebx,loopStack[ecx*4]
    inc ecx
endloop:
    ret
close ENDP

dot PROC
    movzx eax, BYTE PTR [edi]
    invoke putchar, eax
    ret
dot ENDP

comma PROC
    invoke getchar
    mov BYTE PTR [edi], al
    ret
comma ENDP

end EvalBf
```

There are more things that could be improved, such as maximizing register use, but this should get you started.

For reference, I used Visual Studio 12.0.  After setting the environment variables using `vcvarsall.bat` as supplied by Microsoft, the command line to assemble the code was:

> ```
> ml /Fm /Fl /Sa bf.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib
> ```

For comparison, the segment sizess of both the original code (modified minimally to run without masm32) and the modified code above were:

```
                old code       new code
    CONST           0            115 
    _DATA         392            320
    CONST+_DATA   392            435

    _TEXT         330            200
    total         722            635
```

So the result is that the new code is 87 bytes shorter (about 10%) and actually includes code for all 8 of the instruction tokens, so it's actually both shorter and more functional than the original.

Comment: I had used the MASM32 libs because I couldn't persuade Visual Studio to build my code when using `printf` and the other C runtime functions. Are you building from within Visual Studio or just editing it there and then assembling from the command line?

Comment: I don't use the GUI in Visual Studio at all.  I use the [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/) text editor to edit the code and makefile and then build from the command line.